# convert datatable to json using JsonConvert.SerializeObject

Tags: c#, .net, json

Im using JsonConvert.SerializeObject to serialize my datatable.

Everything is ok but I would like to have possibility, to use column caption instead of column names in the result json file.

How can I do that ?

thanks for any hints